# Pages are visually corrupted in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gpu-driver

Pages are loading fine in Chrome, but then some kind of jitter appears. It happens on pages with and without Flash. I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 with Intel HD 3000 video card.

How do can I figure out what's the problem?

**UPD: Same bug happens in Steam client.**

[image: Visual corruption in Chrome]
[image: Visual corruption in Steam]

Comment: This is either a bug in the video card driver, a bug on xorg + video card driver or the video card failing. Have you tried other distros?

Comment: @Braiam could not find this bug reported anywhere, sadly. Other distro is not an option, I might try downgrade though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your issue revolves around one of two things: the GPU drivers for your Intel GPU or Flash (Steam runs on a special version for most of the client), so try re-configuring/re-installing both.

For the GPU, try this: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` (You may need to get rid of the existing one)

As for Flash, the Steam option instructions can  be found [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1493-GHZB-7612), and the standard player version can be found on Adobe's website.

NOTE: I have heard of Flash issues on Chrome for Linux before, you can read a detailed support document [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html) off Adobe's help site.

Restarting the machine in both cases is likely necessary.

Comment: Tried reinstalling driver, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Write `chrome://plugins` on the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
2. Find "Adobe flash player(2 files)" and disable it;

Restart Chrome and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Tried that with no luck.